# How to enable latest Twitter feeds for organization in Sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore7.5

I am working on sitecore 8, I have installed MongoDB and I am wondering how i can get the Social Media enable in my sitecore. I want to show the latest twitter feed of the organization on page. Through some search I got to know sitecore 8 have given this feature out of the box.

Could anyone help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to do it via Sitecore?

Twitter has page for creation widgets: https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new (You should be logged in to Twitter to create widget). You are able to create any widget for organization (by Twitter username), for tag (by Twitter hashtag), etc. You can copy code from Twitter to your sublayout and use it.

It has sense to do it using Sitecore Social only if you want to show different Twitter spots for different Twitter users.(But you said that you want to do it for organization). In this case, please follow documentation on [dev.sitecore.net](http://dev.sitecore.net) or [sdn.sitecore.net](http://sdn.sitecore.net)

Answer (score 0):

widgets are soon to be deprecated, try to use https://publish.twitter.com/ instead, it provides several options to customize how you want the feed to be viewed, and you'll only need to include the html in the layout or specific view you want in sitecore.